# AIR 2.7 iOS App will not quit when hitting iPhone home button

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3, air

When publishing to iOS device the game plays well, when hitting homebutton it disappears as normal, but next time you open it - it starts to play at the state or level it was when quitting - as it only was paused. It should start up from default startupscreen.

does anyone have the same problem?  or solution tho this?

ps we had an 103 error that we solved with this:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/909/cpsid_90916.html

Comment: You must have not heard of iOS 4's multitasking feature.

Comment: @BoltClock I know, right? It's such a behind-the-scenes feature, easy to miss.

Comment: we have been using older Air ios packagers with Flash CS 5.0  theys still quit completely and start from begining/intro of game

Comment: the device we are testing on is an iPhone 3GS. When exported from Flash CS5 and air 2.7  they will start from where you left it before quitting.  Wished user experience should be playing from start of game. is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

When you write an iPhone application, to disable the background mode, you have to set the "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" key to YES in the info.plist file.

When you develop mobile Air application the equivalent of the info.plist is located into the "name of the app"-app.xml. I have never tested it but you may have to specify it there like that:

```
 <iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
            <string>2</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
        <true/>
     ]]></InfoAdditions>
     <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

I hope it'll help you.

Comment: Hi Yannick, thanks a lot!, this code really did the job, and the app behaves exactly as we wanted